# jQuery animate does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        $(document).keydown(function () {
            alert("hello");
            $('div').animate({ left: '+=10px' }, 500);
        });
    });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
     height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: Red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to just move my div to the right on every key down, but for some reason, this won't work. I'm getting the "hello" alert so there is probably some small mistake in the animate statement that I just can't figure out.

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working and the correct way to do it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because left/top/right/bottom properties only apply to positioned elements.

So you either need to use `position:relative`/`position:absolute` on the div, or animate the `margin-left` instead. (*depends on the end result you want..*)

Quote from [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props)

> **9.3.2 Box offsets:** '`top`', '`right`', '`bottom`', '`left`'
>
> An element is said to be positioned if its '**position**' property has a value other than '***static***'. Positioned elements generate positioned boxes, laid out according to four properties:

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Luj2u/)

try this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {           
        $(document).keydown(function () {
            alert("hello");
            $('#tomove').animate({ left: '+=10px' }, 500);
        });
    });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
     height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: Red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tomove"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position to relative on css:

```
position: relative;
```

take a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velthune/dkhBY/20/).

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**
You have to position it first with absolute or relative to move it.

Like this:

```
position: relative;
/* OR */
position: absolute;
```